# Image Slider in C#?

Tags: c#, image, slider

I want to create a simple image slideshow, when the timer switch, it will switch to the next index of the picturebox (and will loop) but with a fade effect. How can it be done in C#?

Current Code doesn't switch images? And also - how can I create the fade ffect?

I created a simple timer with 5,000ms interval, enabled it on start.

```
 private void timerImage_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (pictureBox1.Image.Equals(InnovationX.Properties.Resources._1))
        {
            pictureBox1.Image = InnovationX.Properties.Resources._2;
        }
        else if (pictureBox1.Image.Equals(InnovationX.Properties.Resources._2))
        {
            pictureBox1.Image = InnovationX.Properties.Resources._3;
        }
        else
        {
            pictureBox1.Image = InnovationX.Properties.Resources._1;

        }
    }
```

Comment: pure C# or using WPF?

Comment: @Sharath I've never used WPF, but whatever easier to understand.

Comment: You might need to Invalidate the picturebox. I'd switch to a different kind of comparison too.

Answer (score 1):

You can't compare Bitmap loaded from resource in this manner. Every time you get image from resource (in your case using property `InnovationX.Properties.Resources._1`) you will get new instance of Bitmap class. Comparing two different instances of `Bitmap` classes will always result in false, even if they contains same image.

```
Bitmap a = InnovationX.Properties.Resources._1; // create new bitmap with image 1
Bitmap b = InnovationX.Properties.Resources._1; // create another new bitmap with image 1
bool areSameInstance = a == b; // will be false
```

If you load you images from resources to member variables (e.g. in Load event).

```
// load images when you create a form
private Bitmap image1 = InnovationX.Properties.Resources._1;
private Bitmap image2 = InnovationX.Properties.Resources._2;
private Bitmap image3 = InnovationX.Properties.Resources._3;

// assing and compare loaded images
private void timerImage_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (pictureBox1.Image == image1)
    {
        pictureBox1.Image = image2;
    }
    else if (pictureBox1.Image == image2)
    {
        pictureBox1.Image = image3;
    }
    else
    {
        pictureBox1.Image = image1;
    }
}
```

And after that, rewrite that code using array :)

```
Image[] images = new { 
    InnovationX.Properties.Resources._1, 
    InnovationX.Properties.Resources._2, 
    InnovationX.Properties.Resources._3 
};
```